# Chartkick gem, limit group in pie chart and multiple series

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, charts, highcharts

I have small problem with grouped records. Chart code:

```
<%= pie_chart CountChatLine.group(:channel).count %>
```

The problem is, that I have more than few `:channels` in database, and chart looks like this:
[image]

Can I somehow take only N top `:channels` and sum rest of it as `others` or something? Or add to others every `:channel` that has less than N%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some heavy thinking and @Agazoom help and I've done this.
Code:

```
  @top_count = 5
  @size = CountChatLine.group(:channel).count.count-@top_count 
  @data_top = CountChatLine.group(:channel).order("count_all").reverse_order.limit(@top_count).count 
  @data_other = CountChatLine.group(:channel).order("count_all").limit(@size).count 
  @data_other_final = {"others" => 0} 
  @data_other.each { |name, count| @data_other_final = {"others" => @data_other_final["others"]+count }} 
  @sum_all_data = @data_top.reverse_merge!(@data_other_final)
```

IDK if there is a better way. If there is, please post it. But for now, it works :)

Comment: This worked for me! You could reduce a bit extracting the grouping/order query that is similar to another variable. Other from that, on my case I took your solution and added a single condition at the end: if others == 0, don't add it to the last object, to avoid showing the header on the graph without any data represented.

Answer (score 1):

The chartkick gem (which I just started using),  will chart whatever data you provide it.  It's up to you as to what the data you provide it looks like.

Yes, you can absolutely reduce the number of slices in your pie by aggregating them, however, you need to do that yourself.

You can write a method in your model to summarize this and call is as such:

```
<%= pie_chart CountChatLine.summarized_channel_info %>
```

**method in CountChatLine model:**

```
def self.summarized_channel_info
   {code to get info and convert it into format you really want}
end
```

Hope that helps.  That's what I did.

Comment: Well, I knew it and still wasn't able to figure it out. And also I was wondering if there is simplier way, like just add `, limit: 5` in `.group` part or somethnig. But... I got this: `<%= pie_chart CountChatLine.group(:channel).order("count_all").reverse_order.limit(5).count %>` It works pretty well, but still doesn't count `others`. :/

Comment: Perhaps this is the long way and there is a shorter way, but what you can do is:  grab all the data without a limit,  go through the array of results,  push the top 5 into a new array,  add up the rest, and push the sum onto your new array.   At this point, you will have a top 5 and a 'sum of the rest' in your array.  Feed that to the pie-chart.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if we could have the DB do the work and return the top results, but something like this should work:

```
<%= pie_chart CountChatLine.group(:channel).count.sort_by {|k,v| v}.reverse[0..4] %>
```

[0..4] will show the top 5 largest results. [0..9] would be the top 10.

It is returning the results from the DB
Then sorting them by the value (low to high)
Then reversing the sort (high to low)
Then taking just the top [0..4] results.